# While creating a Docker file for AEM I am getting permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, aem

1. Links I am using https://github.com/auniverseaway/aem-docker
2. I am the root user and so didnt used sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
3. I am getting permission denied  as below

`for aemproject_author_1  Cannot start service author: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"/opt/aem/start\": permission denied"`

4. I have tried sudo docker run projectname , but the same error is coming.

I am new to docker and I dont know how I can change the permissions of the host or underlying files so as to get the permission for the containers running
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like [facebook/fbctf issue 431](https://github.com/facebook/fbctf/issues/431) (about a similar error)

After cloning https://github.com/auniverseaway/aem-docker, try:

```
 chmod +x ./start
```

Then `docker build` and `docker run`